# Django haystack searching for html tags returns all posts

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a django app (blog) which I am trying to implement django haystack with elasticsearch. The problem that I am having is that when testing the search functionality by searching for `<p>` or `<html>` I don't expect any results, however it's returning all my posts. Here is what my app/models look like:

blog/models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    html_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    markdown_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='PostTags')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.html_content = markdown.markdown(
            self.markdown_content,
            ["markdown.extensions.extra", "codehilite"]
        )
        super(Posts, self).save(*args, **kwargs
```

blog/search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes


from .models import Posts


class PostsIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(
        model_attr='text',
        document=True,
        use_template=True
    )
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    markdown_content = indexes.CharField(
        model_attr='markdown_content',
        null=True,
        indexed=False
    )

    html_content = indexes.CharField(
        model_attr='html_content',
        null=True,
        indexed=False
    )

    def get_model(self):
        return Posts

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Now I assume that when I search for `<p>` or `<html>` is returning all my posts because I am saving html tags in the database, am I wrong? If so, how can I specify to ignore any html tags?

I have also tried to use `indexes.ModelSearchIndex` and exclude the field `html_content` and yet searching for html tags seems to return all the posts...Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I'm new to django-haystack and elasticsearch, so if I am doing something really basic wrong I do apologise in advance and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you're modifying your index criteria (in `PostsIndex`), but you're still performing searches on a previously-created index, one that still has the HTML tags. Try running Haystack's [`rebuild_index` management command](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/management_commands.html#rebuild-index). Do this after every change you make to the index configuration until you're satisfied with the behavior.

One other possibility is that Elasticsearch is configured to ignore meta characters like `<` and `>` in search queries, and is therefore producing more results than you expect.